# Bootstrap Tab within Popover isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, popover

Bootstrap's Tabs do not seem to be working for me when used within Bootstrap's Popover.

What happens is following:

```
 1. Popover opens
 2. Active tab on click changes
 3. Tab content is not changing <-- PROBLEM
```

Tabs are created correctly and if you try them outside of popover they work fine.

```
<a class="btn" id="btnPopover" href="#">Launch Popover</a>
<div class="tabbable hide" id="popoverContent">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 15px">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Tab Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Tab Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Tab Content 3</div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
 $("#btnPopover").popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'click',
  title: "Title",
  placement: "bottom",
  content: $("#popoverContent").html()
 });
});
```

What seems to happen with bootstrap in this case is that it duplicates the elements. I planned using further javascript libs and plugins on elements within content tabs, and this makes it pretty much impossible, unless somebody provides a solid workaround. I honestly think this is a valid Bootstrap's bug.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iboros/nCfBf/

Comment: It's not *Bootstrap* that's duplicating the elements. It documents the `content` option as being markup (or markup resulting from a function). It doesn't directly support using elements already in the page. Your code duplicates the elements, by using existing DOM elements, taking their `html`, and providing it to Bootstrap to use for the content. The solution is quite simple: Just remove the elements you're duplicating (as @PSL shows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1:

Remove the existing tab and get its HTML content.

```
$("#btnPopover").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    title: "Title",
    placement: "bottom",
    content: $('#popoverContent').remove().html()
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cKWNv/)

### Option 2:

Use class selector for tabs instead of id selector

i.e

```
<a href=".tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
```

#### Html

```
<div class="tabbable hide" id="popoverContent">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href=".tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href=".tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href=".tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 15px">
        <div class="tab-pane active tab1" >Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane tab2">Tab Content 2</div>
        <div class="tab-pane tab3" >Tab Content 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn" id="btnPopover" href="#">Launch Popover</a>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E3fZ9/)

Comment: Hmm, this really does make the content change, so I will mark this as an answer and I thank you very much. Now, the select2.js that I use on an select element within one of the tabs does not work. 
No errors thrown, while having the dropdown show, but the options aren't. Let me get this onto fiddle.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Infact no need to remove the existing tab, instead we can use class selector itself.

Comment: @iboros Its all cos if Id, BS does nothing but just select the selector, so duplicate ids, first one matches and selection does not happen on the popover one as it appears later in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that, but it seems dirty to leave the elements in the DOM like that.

Comment: Here's the demo of my problem with select2.js within popover.
http://jsfiddle.net/iboros/C9qwG/
Dropdown doesn't seem to work within popover, while outside it works. I am guessing it's because of the same thing as previously.
Hopefully you guys are still around. :)

Comment: @iboros: Probably because that plugin is doing something on DOM ready, and by destroying and recreating the elements, that initialization isn't done. What you really want is an option for the popover to use the existing elements rather than you giving it HTML, which it doesn't look like popover supports.

Comment: So I would need to re-trigger something once tab is clicked?
Oh man, I think I will try doing something with the modal instead of popover, hopefully that doesn't kick my ass too, hehe.

Comment: @iboros: Yeah, and the kicker is that Popover doesn't seem to give any kind of event. :-( Yeah, switching to modal is probably better, it actually uses the elements, rather than having you give it markup.

Comment: @iboros btw your select2 set up works? event with the select outside the popovet it doesn't `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined` . But i think workaround would be to binding it again during `shown` callback. http://jsfiddle.net/2HSBS/

Comment: Yeah, something was wrong with those files. I've added proper ones.
http://jsfiddle.net/iboros/C9qwG/6/
Outside works, inside it doesn't.

Comment: Haha, you are maniacs!!! You got this knowledge in your little finger Thanks so much. :)